# Google API javascript client - Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, api, google-plus

I'm trying to connect the Google client API to get some basic information of the client (name, email ...).

So i use [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js) to try to connect the client API.

I followed all the instructions, I made an OAuth Client on Google Developper Console.

Put my "Client ID" and "Client Secret" in the "var Client ID" and "apiKey" on the code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <button id="authorize-button" style="visibility: hidden">Authorize</button>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      
      var clientId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
      
      var apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
           
      var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me';
      
      function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
        window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
      }
      function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);
      }
      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
          makeApiCall();
        } else {
          authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
        }
      }
      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
        return false;
      }
    
      function makeApiCall() {
        gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function() {
          var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
            'userId': 'me'
          });
          request.execute(function(resp) {
            var heading = document.createElement('h4');
            var image = document.createElement('img');
            image.src = resp.image.url;
            heading.appendChild(image);
            heading.appendChild(document.createTextNode(resp.displayName));
            document.getElementById('content').appendChild(heading);
          });
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <p>Retrieves your profile name using the Google Plus API.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I click in the "Authorize button" and accept the terms in the consent screen the console show me this two errors:

```
"GET https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/plus/v1/rest?fields=rootUr…ePath%2Cresources%2Cparameters%2Cmethods&pp=0&key=ADEcoJRjS6zPKeWplLfNTCiJ 400 (OK)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'people' of undefined"
```

So, my client is undefined, how that is possible? I searched everywhere but didn't find the solution and I am really new at this.